# Resource title internationalization using GeoNetwork harvesting process from GeoServer metadata

Tags: geoserver, geonetwork

We have GeoServer layers with associated metadata (ISO 19139) in three languages (es, en, fr). GeoNetwork makes the harvesting process correctly but, when we need to internationalize the title of the metadata source, we found that the title appears to be only in one language (we have not way to change between those three metadata languages). The title value is recognized from the GeoServer dataset title (not from any metadata field)

[image: Metadata from GeoServer harvesting process]

If you creates the metadata using the next option, **Contribute > Add new record > Dataset > Template for Vector Data in ISO19139**, we found that the option for manage the title of the metadata resource is available in multiple languages.

[image: GeoNetwork metadata creation process]

For the harvesting process, we have installed the next plugins to GeoServer:

- `csw`
- `csw-iso`
- `inspire`
- `metadata`

Is there any option to add internationalization of the title to the metadata source?